# Get request parameters and use them in forms.py as widget parameters

Tags: python, django, forms, request

I need to get request parameters from views.py and use request.LANGUAGE_CODE to translate model object to the active language, since now I'm getting 'strings' object in default language, and not active. How should I proceed, in order to pass arguments from *init* function to a form widget?

From views.py:

```
form = ContactForm(lang=request.LANGUAGE_CODE)
```

forms.py:

```
from django import forms                                                        
from phonenumber_field.formfields import PhoneNumberField                       
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _                         
from django.utils import translation                                            
from .models import *                                                           

strings = Strings.objects.language().get(pk=1)                  

class ContactForm(forms.Form):                                                  
    phone = PhoneNumberField(                                                      
        min_length=9,                                                           
        max_length=20,                                                          
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={                                          
            'id': 'phone-number',                                               
            'placeholder': strings.placeholder,                                 
        })                                                                      
    )                                                                           

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):                                        
        self.lang = kwargs.pop('lang', None)                                    
        super(ContactForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.lang = kwargs.pop('lang', None)
    super(ContactForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)  
    form.fields['phone'].widget.attrs['placeholder'] = strings.placeholder[self.lang]
```

Of course, you should implement `strings.placeholder[self.lang]` part (it is just an example) to localize your strings by language code.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hey thanks, it did really help! Instead of getting my string by 'lang' value, I created a 'string' object inside __init__ function instead of outside the class, and it then returned the active language.

Comment: last two lines: 
                    
 `strings = Strings.objects.language().get(pk=1)                    
 self.fields['phone'].widget.attrs['placeholder'] = strings.placeholder`

Comment: @Riddle00 its up to you! Glad to help.